# Нахождение рекуррентной зависимости между очередным и предыдущим членом последовательности

Tags: математика

Дана формула суммы:
[image: формула суммы]

Необходимо найти рекуррентную зависимость между очередными и предыдущими членами последовательности. Абсолютно не понимаю, как ее искать.

Был вариант: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, ничего общего он с рекуррентной зависимостью не имеет. Реализация этой формулы в коде предполагает рекурсию функции, а в задании требуется решение через цикл.

Прошу помощи

Comment: Рекурсию можно реализовать через цикл. Судя по тому, что гуглится, это именно рекуррентная формула.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельно считаете числитель и знаменатель. На каждом шаге к числителю прибавить 2, а знаменатель умножить на несколько чисел.

Можно и одно число от прошлого шага держать, только придется умножать на 2k+1 и делить на 2k-1